# Fix "Quota exceed error" in CloudKit and view container usage

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, quota

I have an app that uses CloudKit for data synchronisation.
With a larger volume of users, the data synchronisation between devices stopped working with an error:

```
<CKError 0x600001bbaca0: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; uuid = 6D5A9621-7F98-4813-B7FC-1AE08E0AD16B; 
container ID = "iCloud.EvenyCloudKit"; 
partial errors: {
    3587C9C7-9E2C-460B-855B-C921EC4BDA3A:(com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__) = 
<CKError 0x600001bbac40: "Quota Exceeded" (25/2035);
 server message = "Quota exceeded"; uuid = 6D5A9621-7F98-4813-B7FC-1AE08E0AD16B;
 Retry after 347.0 seconds>
}>
```

I deployed my CloudKit schema to production, but it didn't fix the problem.
I have about 800 active users, and only small text data are stored in CloudKit.
How can I fix this problem, and how can I see the current CloudKit Container usage?

Thanks!
[image: CloudKit Dashboard]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerror/2325197-quotaexceeded

Comment: The problem is, that I cannot find a way how to perform the following step: "you can go to the CloudKit Dashboard to view and manage your container's storage". I cannot see that option in my CloudKit console.